# SQL Server Reporting Services Dynamic Header

Tags: reporting-services

I've created a `.rdlc` report in Visual Studio, I'm assigning data to the report, but as the content is based on the user choosing a region, I'd like to change the report to include the region.

Does anyone have a walk through of how to set this up in really simple terms? I can see that I can put a text box in the header, but what do I do to then change that at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

The Expression for the text box would have something like:

`=Parameters!Region.Label`